# n-th child does not work on local machine

Tags: jquery, html, css

My question is about selectivizr.js. (could not put this in the tag)

Please take a look this [page](http://www.wmxgalaxy.com/tmp/) in IE8.  You'll see that n-th child and last child are both working.  But if you download the html, css and selectivizr.js to your local machine the n-th child and last-child will stop working.  Why is that?  Is there a rule that I am not following?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Ain't that odd. I almost didn't believe you, but independently reproduced.

Answer (score 3):

From the notes hidden at the bottom of the selectivizr home page:

> Style sheets MUST be hosted on the same domain as the page due to browser security restrictions. Likewise, style sheets loaded using the file: protocol will not work.

I bet it's the last thing, about the "file:" effective URLs of the stylesheet. Looking at the source to "selectivizr", it uses XHR to re-fetch style sheets.  Modern browsers (bet it won't work in Chrome either) are much more suspicious of file: URLs than browsers used to be.

*edit* — the OP points out the it works fine in Chrome, which is probably because Chrome doesn't need help from selectivizr to do CSS3 stuff properly :-)

Comment: I does work in chrome and firefox, just fyi. Not real familiar with selectivizr but since it's designed specifically for IE, i'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Ah well duhh, yes it works in Chrome because Chrome already does all the CSS3 stuff :-)  Sorry.  But IE has the same sort of restrictions on local ("file:") URLs.  You might see whether playing around with IE security settings makes a difference.

Comment: Okay I will research IE security settings. Thanks.